# Como colocar um código quando você adiciona um commandbutton?

Tags: vba, button

então eu não sei muito bem como usar isso, de perguntas e tal. Mas tipo, eu tenho uma sub em vba  que quando executada cria um objeto(um botão). 
Ela esta funcionando na parte de cria-lo mas preciso que quando ela o crie, que faça ele receber 2 módulos. Tipo quando editamos o código de um botão normal e colocamos os módulos para ele chamar.
Ex: de um botão normal.

```
Private Sub btnVerifica_Click()

Call Iniciar
Call Teste

End Sub
```

E essa é a minha sub que esta criando o novo botão.

```
Sub CriarBotao()
    Dim Obj As Object
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select

    'Criado o botão
    Set Obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=200, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=35)
    Obj.Name = "BoutonTest"
    'teste do botão
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Caption = "Testar o botão "
End Sub
```

Só que ele não faz nada, e eu não sei como colocar aqueles dois módulos anteriores dentro deste. Poderiam me ajudar , por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão de código:

```
Sub CriarBotao()

    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select

    'Criado o botão
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Left:=200, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=35).Select
    Selection.Name = "BoutonTest"
    Selection.Text = "Testar o botão"
    Selection.OnAction = "Clique"

End Sub

Sub Clique()

    Call Iniciar
    Call Teste

End Sub
```